# FormView datasource lost on button click in another formview

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, formview

I want to preface this by saying that I am a beginner to asp.net, especially when it comes to working with the `FormView` controls. I have searched long and hard and have spent hours debugging this issue.

I have 3 `FormViews` on one aspx page. Each `FormView` has its own `EditItemTemplate` and `PagerTemplate` with `DefaultMode="Edit"`. I am not using a `SqlDataSource`, but instead databinding programatically on the `PageLoad` when `if(!Page.IsPostBack)` and also calling the databinding method when the `PageIndexChanging` method is called. The pager template contains a 'Back' and a 'Next' button set with `CommandArgument="Prev"` and `CommandArgument="Next"`, respectively, and both set with `CommandName="Page"`.

The paging works great on the first `FormView`. When I hit the back or next button, it pages (i.e. re-binds) appropriately. During the 1st `FormView`'s paging event, I also successfully call the binding methods for the 2nd and 3rd `FormView` since I want them to bind data that is specific to the page selected in the 1st `FormView`.

But, when I page back to the first page of the 1st `FormView` (i.e. `PageIndex = 0`), and then try to page forward in the 2nd `FormView`, the datakey for the 1st `FormView` is null. In fact, the `formview1.DataSource` is null for the 1st `FormView` when I try to click a navigation button on the 2nd `FormView`.

Then, here's where I thought it was weird, ... if I click back a second time on the 1st `FormView`, THEN the `formview1.DataSource` is fine, and I can then navigate in the 2nd `FormView`.

All viewstates for the formviews and the buttons are set to true. 
I have tried calling `formview1.DataBind()` inside `formview2`'s paging event before any paging occurs but no success there. I have also tried setting properties: `UseSubmitBehavior="False"` and `CausesValidation="False"` on the paging buttons. Admittedly, I did this without really understanding the behavior but rather implemented after seeing it suggested in solutions for other somewhat related problems.

The templates are rather long since there are many fields in each. But the `FormView` tags look like this:

```
<asp:FormView ID="fvHeader" runat="server" DataKeyNames="ObjectID" DefaultMode="Edit" AllowPaging="True" OnModeChanging="fvHeader_ModeChanging" OnPageIndexChanging= "fvHeader_PageIndexChanging"> 
<EditItemTemplate> ..... </EditItemTemplate> </asp:FormView>
```

PagerTemplates:

```
       <PagerSettings Mode="NextPrevious" />
       <PagerTemplate>
           <span class="labels">Page: <%#fvHeader.PageIndex+1%> of <%#fvHeader.PageCount %></span>&nbsp;
           <asp:Button ID="btnBack" runat="server" CommandArgument="Prev" CommandName="Page" CssClass="btnHdr" Text="&lt;&lt; Back" />&nbsp;
           <asp:Button ID="btnNext" runat="server" CommandArgument="Next" CommandName="Page" CssClass="btnHdr" Text="Next &gt;&gt;" />&nbsp;</PagerTemplate>
```

Note that '`fvHeader`' is what I'm calling '`formview1`' for simplicity in my question.

Back/Next buttons C# code and databinding the 1st formview:

```
    protected void fvHeader_PageIndexChanging(object sender, FormViewPageEventArgs e)
            {
                    fvHeader.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
                    bindFV_Initial(); 

                    //rebind fvSub1 (2nd formview) to get the 1st obs of the newly selected header record
                    fvSub1.ChangeMode(FormViewMode.Edit);
                    fvSub1.PageIndex = 0;
                    bindSub1_Initial();

//rebind 2nd subform
                    fvSub2.ChangeMode(FormViewMode.Edit);
                    fvSub2.PageIndex = 0;
                    bindSub2_Initial(); 

            }
     private void bindFV_Initial()
            {
                    if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                    {
                        conn.Close();
                    }

                    conn.Open();

                    if (dtEOS == null || dtEOS.Rows.Count == 0)
                    {
                        sqlda = new SqlDataAdapter("USE dbWEF SELECT * FROM tblHeader WHERE [UserID] = '" + Session["User"] + "' AND [ProjectName] = '" + Session["Project"] + "'", conn); 
                        sqlda.Fill(dtEOS);
                    }

                    fvHeader.DataSource = dtEOS;
                    fvHeader.DataBind();

                    conn.Close();

                    if (dtEOS.Rows.Count > 0)
                    {
                        fillDD_fvHeader(); //Fill dropdowns and databind ddls
                    }
                }

            }
```

Below is the error message I receive when I attempt to navigate the 2nd formview.

```
    Error in: bindSub1_Initial.
    System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
    Parameter name: index
   at System.Collections.ArrayList.get_Item(Int32 index)
   at System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary.get_Item(Int32 index)
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataKey.get_Item(Int32 index)
   at RenewableEnergyDataEntry.Forms.EagleObservationSurvey.bindSub1_Initial()
```

During debugging, I find that this error occurs right when the 2nd formview is being binded because the datatable is empty which is a result of it needing the datakey from formview1 to pull the correct data, which again, is null because formview1's datasource goes to null. But clicking formview's back button one more time, refills and KEEPS the datasource, thereby allowing formview2 to fill and navigate perfectly. So strange...

Comment: Show your code for Back/Next button click event handlers and the data binding code. I think your instinct that something is not being databound properly is correct.

Comment: Where is dtEOS defined and why are you checking for it for before the rebind?  Have a feeling getting rid of that check will make your binding issue go away.

Comment: it is defined under partial public class: 
DataTable dtEOS = new DataTable(); 
I wanted to minimize the number of connections out to the SQL db, so if dtEOS is already filled once, then there's no reason to fill it again was my logic. Either way, I removed the if checks on dtEOS and still have the same error. I will update question with error message.

Comment: The page is recreated each time it is requested, so you are not saving anything unless you are making multiple calls on each post back. Might want to think about separating out your database logic into its own class, so your page can just request data, but that's a conversation for another day.

Comment: Yes, separating it out into its own class is in the works. Haven't implemented it yet but yes, thank you. Would just really love to get this paging thing to work.

Comment: My guess is you have another code path that is causing the page not to be bound on post back. Do you have any other code checking the condition of your dtEOS table before binding?

Comment: If that's the case, I have no idea where it is. There is no other code that uses the datatable dtEOS other than in bindFV_Initial()

Comment: There is probably some other place you need to call the bind then.

Comment: It's very weird. I noticed other strange behavior when paging back that does not occur when paging forward. Instead of continuing to rip my hair out, I opted to just write my own methods to handle the paging button clicks. So far so good. Thanks for the tips you provided.

Comment: Good to hear.  The ASP.NET form event model can be an adventure.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you simplify you code.
more than likely you are creating conflicts with the view state.
We can't see where and how your dataSource: (dtEOS) is being defined.
But I am going to guess that it's being reset conditionally on a call back.
This is a common problem in ASP.net (conflict with view sate and /or  databinding).

Try using a grid instead of a formview and it will handle the paging much more gracefully without needing a postback and data rebind.